# How can I disable the error popup showed in Anaconda plugin for SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

When I running a test or a file and it has an error, [AnacondaST3](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/#) shows this error popup:

[image]

But it's annoying because I have to close it with the mouse.

How can I disable this red popup?

Comment: Turn off `show_errors_inline`

Comment: Didn't work =/ .   I've tried  "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none" as well, but didnt work

Comment: I don't think that is linter behaviour; I don't use the plugin myself but everything it has to say about linters doesn't mention phantoms or inline errors (which is what those are); if it was linting it would show gutter marks and/or colored outlines around the errors. It's telling that it only does that for tests but I see no option to turn off test errors. Well behaved plugins should have a setting or at least honour `show_errors_inline`.